# Can't get a json response from Cakephp 3 controller

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to send an ajax request to a Cakephp 3 controller.

The controller will find the data from the model and return it to the same view to be displayed,

The view and the js function are as follows

```
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "<?php echo $this->Url->build(['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'getByCategories', '_ext' => 'json']); ?>",
            success: function (data){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
    });
});</script>
```

The above function is in the index view of the controller.

Upon the click of the button a request will be sent to the getByCategories function in the same controller.

The getByCategories function is as follows

```
public function getByCategories()
{
    $id = 33;
    $this->request->allowMethod(['ajax']);
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $cat = $this->Users->Categories->get($id);
    if ($this->Users->Categories->childCount($cat) > 0)
    {
        $result = $this->Users->Categories->find('all', ['conditions' => ['parent_id' => $id]]);
        $this->set(compact($result));
        $this->set('_serialize', $result);
    }
    else
    {
        $result['Machines'] = $this->Users->Machines->find('all', ['conditions' => ['category_id' => $id]]);
        $result['Medias'] = $this->Users->Medias->find('all', ['conditions' => ['category_id' => $id]]);
        $this->set(compact($result));
        $this->set('_serialize', $result);
    }
}
```

The ajax response from this function is alway empty but the debugkit display the _serialize variable correctly.

I have enabled the json extensions in the routes.php file. the variable for the this call in the debugkit is as follows

[debugkit varables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Kiqa.png)

I would appreciated if someone can guide to get the variable from the debugkit in the ajax response

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're close, except for a misunderstanding of how `_serialize` (and maybe either `set` or `compact`) works. Check [the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key) for all the details, but what you should be setting in `_serialize` is either a list of *names of* variables, or else `true` to serialize everything.

Also, if you're using `compact` with `set`, you give it *names of* variables, not the variables themselves.

So, what you should be using there is probably:

```
$this->set(compact('result'));
$this->set('_serialize', ['result']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. now i am getting in the debugkit 2 variables: _serialize and result but the data variable in the javascript function is always an empty string. and when i try to parse data i get this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input". Sorry for these silly questions but i am relativly new to cakephp thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't done JSON output so I don't know if there's common things that might trip you up there. Have you tried visiting the URL directly with your browser to see what output you get? You presumably have something like `$routes->extensions(['json']);` in your `config/routes.php`.

Comment: Thank you greg you were very helpful